# Umbraco Truncate

Tags: html, razor, umbraco, truncate

Umbraco Truncate doesn't seem the work for me, it constantly errors while I'm using the right code (according to the internet). I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

**Error code:**

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Truncate(System.Web.IHtmlString, int)' has some invalid arguments
```

**Code:**

```
<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <figure>
                    <a href="@item.Url">
                        @if (@item.GetPropertyValue("image") != null)
                        {
                            <img src="@Umbraco.Media(item.GetPropertyValue("image").ToString()).Url?anchor=center&mode=crop&w=400&h=275"/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h5>@item.GetPropertyValue("title")</h5>
                            <p>@Umbraco.Truncate(item.GetPropertyValue("intro"),200)</p>
                        </figcaption>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <figcaption>
                                <h5>@item.GetPropertyValue("title")</h5>
                                <p>@item.GetPropertyValue("intro")</p>
                            </figcaption>
                        }
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </div>
```

Not sure why `<p>@Umbraco.Truncate(item.GetPropertyValue("intro"),200)</p>` does not work

Comment: What datatype is "intro"?

Comment: Intro has the datatype textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
@Umbraco.Truncate(item.GetPropertyValue<string>("intro"), 200);
```

instead of

```
@Umbraco.Truncate(item.GetPropertyValue("intro"), 200);
```

because `item.GetPropertyValue("intro")` is of type `object` and you need `string` as the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about that one.

Comment: Yup, beat me to it :-)